# How to get value of a cell based on key on neighboring cell in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, parsing

**Input**:

I have the following data;

|  | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $1 | ABC |
| 2 | $2 | ABC |
| 3 | $3 | DEF |
| 4 | $4 | ABC |

I want to create another table in the same sheet where I want to add the values in Column `C` based on the keys in Column `D`.

**Output**:

|  | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | $7 |
| 2 | DEF | $3 |

Here $7 is the sum of values corresponding to ABC and $3 is the sum of values corresponding to DEF.

So I need something like `"= Sum of values in Column C corresponding to Key in G1 found in Column D"` in H1 and so on...

What's the best way to achieve this instead of adding the values manually?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: " I want to add the values in Column A based on the keys in Column B", where are those two colums? You have only shown C and D.

Comment: Sorry, edited it now. But, I also found the solution which I posted as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `SUMIF`.

The formula for H1 would be:

`=SUMIF(D:D,G1,C:C)`

Alternatively, you can also use Pivot table to group and sum the values of column C based on column D.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data:

[image: Sample Data]

In cell **C10**, use this formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$5=B10)*$B$2:$B$5)`. Drag down to  fill other cells in the column:

[image: Final]

You'll get the sum of all matched values.